# VideoView not working

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I tried to open a mp4 video like this :

```
VideoView myVideoView = new VideoView(this);
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path[idImage]));
myVideoView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
myVideoView.requestFocus();
myVideoView.start();
```

but I don't see nothing on screen. What did I missed?

My xml file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main">

    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ViewFlipper>

    <VideoView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:id="@+id/VideoView"></VideoView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please look into LogCat and say whether there are some log messages of the video view.

Comment: I don't have any message on LogCat. Before this code I have a System.out.println with a message. I see this message on LogCat and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to declare a VideoView tag in your layout e.g.

```
<VideoView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:id="@+id/VideoView"></VideoView>
```

and instantiate using:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
// Set video link (mp4 format )
Uri video = Uri.parse(path[idImage]);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: With this code I can hear the video but not see it. At the begining of the video I see the buttons for control the video. I must play a video when a image is pressed. When I press the image, the image stays on screen and I hear the video(but not see it).

Comment: I think that xml file is the problem. I edited my question with my xml. I can't do the viewFlipper by code, so it must be declarated on xml file.

Comment: your view flipper seems to have fill_parent height so maybe it's pushing the videoview off screen?

Comment: yes, this is the problem. I created a new xml file for videoview and I called setContentView(R.layout.video).

Comment: I can't make this working in watching streaming with VideoView. Controller seems not respond to commands...

Comment: Where this code should be implemented in the JAVA file?

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm answering an already answered question but it might help someone who lands here by search.

I couldn't get Android's VideoView from API example to play any file, but it was a mistake on my part.

1. I've type path from the root, example **/videoFileName.mp4** and I should have type it with sdcard in between like **/sdcard/videoFileName.mp4**
2. My Sony Ercisson Xperia Arc was connected as a usb mass device storage at the same time I was running my app through adb, so internal sd card was unmounted and file could not be found. I've discovered this when I tryed same code on Samsung Galaxy S which behaves differently when connected.